# How to get the following result?

Tags: oracle

How to get the following result ?

Input : -

```
  t1
 --------------
 col1 col2 col3
 --------------
 101, abc, 100
 101, xyz, 200
 101, rst, 300
 -------------
```

Output : -

```
101 abc 100 xyz 200 rst 300
```

Comment: which version of oracle?

Comment: the order of result is important?

Comment: Ok, I've put a query in 11g which maintains the order.

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
SELECT col1, replace(wm_concat(col2||col3),',', '')  FROM t1 GROUP BY col1;
```

or

```
SELECT col1, (SELECT XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, X1.col2||col3)order by X1.col2).extract('//text()')
            FROM t1 X1 WHERE X1.col1=X.col1)
FROM t1 X
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with 11g and maintains the order of items.

```
select LISTAGG (code, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn, coln)
from(

    select code, min(rn) as rn, min(coln) as coln
    from(
       select col1 as code, rownum rn, 1 as coln from t order by col1, col3
       union all
       select col2 as code, rownum rn, 2 as coln from t order by col1, col3
       union all
       select col3 as code, rownum rn, 3 as coln from t order by col1, col3
       )
    group by code
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
select col1 || ' ' || listagg( col2 || ' ' || col3, ' ' ) within group ( order by COL3 ) 
from t1
group by col1;
```